# Fast way to get Word range as xml in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, office-interop

my code:

```
 //  use MS-Word Interop
 var rangeList = doc.Sentences.ofType<Range>().ToList();//About 4000 Sentences
 foreach (var range in rangeList)
  {
          string sentXml=range.get_XML(false);//get all sentences xml,it's very slow ,about 18 min
          //ConvertToFlowDocument(sentxml);
   }
```

but it is very slow.
 how do i convert range.WordOpenXML to openxml elements or etc...

yes,i also use `range.Copy()` to Convert to rtf string,it is also slow.

Comment: First, your code doesn't include the actual conversion. Second, *why* do you read each individual sentence as if it were a separate document instead of just converting `doc`? If you have 100 sentences, you are creating, opening and converting 100 documents, instead of converting a single one.

Comment: now i want get each sentence and style to display in the RichTextBox.

Comment: i used openxml get Range's Text and RunProperties is very fast,now I want to use MS-Word Interop

Comment: Taking your question literally, the only way to *convert* Word content to RTF is either via the Clipboard (i.e. Range.Copy) or to save it to a new file. In this case that would mean transferring the content to a new document then using SaveAs on that document to create an RTF file. I think that Range.Copy() will be faster than saving to a new file...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `Range.XML`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.xml?view=word-pia

```
string sentXml = string.Empty;
//Use MS-W Word Interop    
foreach (var range in doc.Sentences) 
//You don't need to create a list variable because Sentences implements IEnumerable
  
    string sentXml += range.XML; //Get XML for all sentences
    //ConvertToFlowDocument(sentxml);
}
```

I'm not sure how you are going about it , but it would be helpful if you showed what the `get_Xml` method does. Based on your comments, it sounds like my method may be faster. You can open up a `StreamReader`, and then insert the `XML` inside.

```
WordprocessingDocument MainWordDocument;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m_MainWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
{

     string docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

     //Then, you can replace any text that you want
     //string textToReplace("");
     //docText = docText.Replace("what you want to replace", "some xml string that you extracted");

     //Or you can just add it onto the end.
     string docText = docText + sentXml;
     
     //Open a StreamWriter and write overwrite the file
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
     {
          writer.Write(docText);
     }
 }
```

I don't think this is the most efficient way of doing things and don't know why someone would you use both `WordInterop` and `OpenXML` together, and this question is quite old, but this answers your question. If you think that there is a good use case for using the two together, I'd be interested to hear about it.